# How to replace jquery attr multiple times from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to replace jQuery attr by user input correctly? Now I'm getting always same result (user's first input). I guess my code now adds always new data attribute to my button but browser reads only first one.

Simplified:
I want that when user first write to input field "flower" and presses the button opens http://example.com/flowertherest/ and second time when user writes "car" and after button click opens http://example.com/cartherest/.

My Javascript

```
  function funCtion() {
    var url = $('#url').val();
    urli = '../url.php?url=http://example.com/'+url+'therest/';
    $('#fan').attr('data-src', urli); // sets
  }
```

My HTML code

```
    <input type ="text" id="txtName" placeholder="URL" class="form-control" />
    <input type ="button" id="fan" onclick="funCtion()" value="AVAA!" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Fanseat" class="btn btn-default" /><br /><br />
```

Comment: May you post your `click` function?

Comment: txtName is set but not used afterwards. can you explain ? It may be a bug only.

Comment: I made that bug just by editing my code to here. I simplified/edited it now.

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.href = urli` in your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kirit, already spotted it...the issue is more that the id of the text input should be 'url' instead of 'txtName' or change the code to read correctly:

To make sure your data refreshes use the [programatic api](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api), this worked for me:

```
<input type ="text" id="url" placeholder="URL" class="form-control" />
    <input type ="button" id="fan" onclick="funCtion()" value="AVAA!"  />

<script type="text/javascript">

function funCtion() {
    var url = $('#url').val();
    urli = '../url.php?url=http://example.com/'+url+'therest/';

$.fancybox.open({
    src  : urli,
    opts : {
        caption : urli
    }
});
    console.log(urli)
  }

</script>
```

Comment: In console log works properly but still opens always first inputted address.

Comment: Can you show what is id 'fan'? just to see how expect to follow the url...i also @DrKey mentions another option, to use: window.location.href to navigate..

Comment: That window.location.href is working but I want to use fancybox in this case. And now it fires correctly already when button pressed first time.

Comment: Fancybox got some update this morning and after that everything works fine even without that modifying! :-D Thank you god. But tested also that and it works better way.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help for you.

```
$('#fan').click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
var txtName = $('#txtName').val();
urli = '../url.php?url=http://example.com/'+txtName+'therest/';
$('#fan').attr('data-src', urli); // sets
```

});

Answer (score 0):

1) Get the text value using id like this `$('#txtName').val();`

2) And concatenate  it with url

```js
function funCtion() {
    var url = $('#txtName').val();
    urli = '../url.php?url=http://example.com/'+url+'therest/';
    $('#fan').attr('data-src', urli);
     console.log($('#fan').attr('data-src'));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="text" id="txtName" placeholder="URL" class="form-control" />
    <input type ="button" id="fan" onclick="funCtion()" value="AVAA!" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Fanseat" class="btn btn-default" /><br /><br />
```

Comment: Also this works correctly in console log but in network tab I see always same (first inputted) page opening...

Comment: `<fieldset>
  <p><label>SHORT Text</label></p>
    <input type ="text" id="txtName" placeholder="URL" class="form-control" />
    <input type ="button" id="fan" onclick="funCtion()" value="AVAA!" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Fanseat" class="btn btn-default" />
  </fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/pagescriptwhereisjavascript.js?v=3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox.js"></script>`